# Laravel 7 - No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js, cors, laravel-7

I know this is a very common problem and there is a lot of other questions about it, however, I don't know what to do anymore. I have upgraded my Laravel API application from `5.8` to `7.10.3` and now I'm facing this `CORS` issue that didn't happen before. Laravel 7 already provides the `fruitcake/laravel-cors` package and this is my configuration (default config) in `config/cors.php`:

```
'paths' => ['api/*'],
'allowed_methods' => ['*'],
'allowed_origins' => ['*'],
'allowed_origins_patterns' => [],
'allowed_headers' => ['*'],
'exposed_headers' => [],
'max_age' => 0,
'supports_credentials' => false,
```

Basically every `origin`, `headers` and `methods` are allowed. I've even tried  to add these lines to `bootstrap/app.php` but it won't worked:

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: *');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: *');
```

My frontend is built with `VueCli 3` and I didn't make any changes on it, just upgraded Laravel version.

Requests on `POSTMAN` are working fine. Does anyone have any idea of why this problem is happening?

Full error message:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/operacao/cadastrar' from origin 'http://localhost:8080' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

Answer (score 1):

I've found the problem: My request was failing in the `$request->validate()` method and it was inside a `try / catch` block with a custom exception handler like this:

```
try {
    $request->validate(array(...)); //validation was failing
    //code...
} catch (\Exception $e) {
    //This was the problem
    http_response_code(400);
    die($e->getMessage());
}
```

Just put `$request->validate()` before `try` and it worked. Just remembering that `validate()` has its own exception handler.

I don't know exactly why this was causing a CORS error but I think that's because it was sending the `headers` before the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` etc.

Comment: No idea what you are talking about. I have the same issue in my vue + laravel 7 application. I'm using "ionic icons". When the home.vue page loading, I get this error. The font icons won't load.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue using REACT and my solution was to add Headers and format my request like this.

```
axios.request({
      method: "POST",
      url: '<url>',
      data: data,
      headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
   })
   .then(function (response) {
     <what to do if works>
   })
   .catch((response) => {
    <what to do if it doesn't work>
   })
```

Comment: Hi Lucas! Thanks for your help! I've already found the problem, see my answer below :)

Comment: Glad you found the problem!